# Автонастройка на нужное устройство modbus

Tags: c#, modbus

Есть приложение wpf, которое общается с устройством, которое подключается по rs485 и работает по протоколу modbus.
Пример чтения регистров:
запрос - 01 03 00 00 00 02 C4 0B

Где:
Первый байт - номер устройства (адрес)
Второй байт - номер функции (03 = чтение регистров)
Третий и четвертый - адрес начала регистров (0000)
Пятый и шестой - количество регистров (0002)
Последние два байта - контрольная сумма.
Ранее было известно какой адрес был у устройства. После прихода новых железок, адреса стали меняться, а широковещательный запрос (0х00) стал не проходить. Нужно реализовать настройку на работающее устройство. 
У меня есть команда на чтение byte {}= (0х01, 0x03,0x00 ,0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xC4, 0х0B)

Все классно, если известен адрес. Но как сделать корректно перебор адресов? т.е. сначала отправляем (0х01, 0x03,0x00 ,0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xC4, 0х0B), если нет ответа (0х02, 0x03,0x00 ,0x00, 0x00, 0x02, ..,..),если нет (0х03, 0x03,0x00 ,0x00, 0x00, 0x02, ..,..) итд.

Адрес находится в диапазоне от 1 до 254, т.е. занимает 1 байт.

Comment: Для этого есть циклы. Меняйте первый байт в запросе. В чем проблема?

Comment: с циклами понятно. не совсем ясно, как сделать правильней. определяем к примеру список/массив/... из всех возможных значений (их к примеру 254)  и далее идем по массиву? есть какой-либо более красивый способ? Смысл в том, чтобы не определять все адреса

Comment: Ну, у вас есть команда на чтение. По сути меняется только первый байт, который адрес устройства. Создаете цикл от 1 до 254, в каждом шаге цикла меняете первый байт, посылаете команду, ждете ответа(сколько там максимум по стандарту) если ответа нет - делаете следующий шаг цикла, если ответ пришел - выходите из цикла с выводом текущего адреса устройства. Вам нужно найти адрес устройства только один раз на железку(процесс не быстрый получается), записать его куда нть, либо нацарапать на самом устройстве, а затем вводить его вручную.

Comment: Спасибо, это теоретически понятно. Я правильно понимаю, мне нужен цикл от 1 до 254, в первых 9 случаях понятно 0Х01/0Х02...0Х09, затем 10-ую итерацию я перевожу из 10 системы в 16-ую, т.е получая 10 итерацию, первый байт команды адреса будет 0х0A  итд. Правильно? На 11 итерации адрес 0х0B

Comment: Найти и записать возможно, но идет в разрез с требованием к реализации.

Answer (score 1):

ПО стандарту modbus должно быть до 247 вроде бы, хотя если железка не полностью соответствует стандарту может и 254. Другого способа нет. Хотя возможно есть другой способ подключения. У меня например встречался прибор при подключении по USB которому ни адрес ни скорость не нужен, да их надо указать, но можно любые. может и там также?